# Compiling error while installing a package after updating R

Tags: r, github, installation, r-package

I have recently updated my R to the latest version, 4, and I am getting an error while installing a certain package that I had before. So the error I get is as follow:

```
        > devtools::install_github("ShirinG/exprAnalysis", build_vignettes=F, ref = "master")
    
        √  checking for file 'C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIj39So\remotes10447cb078e0\ShirinG-exprAnalysis-f615bcf/DESCRIPTION' ...
        -  preparing 'exprAnalysis': √  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...     Warning in grepl(e, files, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE) :
             PCRE pattern compilation error
            'unrecognized character follows \'
            at 'inst\extdata\*'    Error in grepl(e, files, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE) : 
             invalid regular expression '^\inst\extdata\*'    Execution halted Error: Failed to install 'exprAnalysis' from GitHub:   System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr: E> * checking for file 'C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIj39So\remotes10447cb078e0\ShirinG-exprAnalysis-f615bcf/DESCRIPTION' ... OK 
    E> * preparing 'exprAnalysis': 
    E> * checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK 
E> Warning in grepl(e, files, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE) : 
    E>   PCRE pattern compilation error E>  'unrecognized character follows \' 
    E>  at 'inst\extdata\*' E> Error in grepl(e, files, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE) :  
    E>   invalid regular expression '^\inst\extdata\*' E> Execution halted
```

Does any one have any suggestion or solution? I am using rtools4 also.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I am encountering a similar problem

Comment: Hello! sorry for late reply! I solved this and if I remember correctly I simply downloaded the github files and used a local installation mode